# Unable to run a clojure library (clojure.data.json) from a file

Tags: clojure, libraries, require, leiningen

I cannot use a library that I added to my project. I keep getting this error:

```
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: No such namespace: json, compiling:
```

the library is clojure.data.json to parse json.
I added the library in the project.clj  dependencies:

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.0"]
             [org.clojure/data.json "2.0.1"]
             [ring "1.8.0"]]
```

in core.clj, I require the library:

```
(ns todo-list.core
(:require  [clojure.data.json :as json]
         [ring.adapter.jetty :as webserver]))
```

I am using Atom, and I can evaluate a function directly. When I evaluate the following function, I get the error above:

```
(def posts (json/read-str (slurp "data.json") :key-fn keyword))
```

I ran the command: lein install in the command line. still not working

Can anyone tell me what's going on please? especially that I can use other libraries without a problem, for example: clojure.string :as str

Answer (score 2):

In Atom, did you evaluate the ns form (or load the whole file after saving it, once you'd added that ns form)?

You can't evaluate just an expression containing `(json/read-str ..)` unless you have first evaluated the `ns` form and required the namespace to create the alias.

Comment: Hi Sean. I tried to evaluate the ns form and I get this error: FileNotFoundException Could not locate clojure/data/json__init.class or clojure/data/json.clj on classpath

Comment: @omar Had you added the dependency after firing up your REPL? Have you tried restarting the REPL your editor sends commands to?

Comment: yes I tried! I even started a new project from scratch. And I added the dependency again in the project.clj. I ran len deps :tree  and I can see the dependency is being added. But when I run the project it's always throwing the error message. What is it I am missing. So frustrating!!!

Comment: Does it work on commandline? Or only in Atom.  Can you share your second attempt of the project (assuming it's tiny since you only did the minimal steps to reproduce it) via github or whatever?